# Use two serial ports on same COM port - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a weighbridge application, where I am using a serial port to get the weights from the weighbridge.

I need to take the weights two times. One with the empty lorry and then with the loaded lorry. I just wonder if I can use two serial ports, one for weighing empty lorry and the other for weighing loaded one? something like

```
 spWeighIn = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
 spWeighOut = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

and use them simultaneously

Thanks

This is my code:

```
    SerialPort spWeigh;
    string strResponseWeigh;

    private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        spWeigh = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        spWeigh.RtsEnable = false;
        spWeigh.DtrEnable = false;
        spWeigh.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        spWeigh.ReadTimeout = 10000;   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!spWeigh.IsOpen)
            spWeigh.Open();
        spWeigh.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(spWeigh_DataInReceived);
        spWeigh.Write("W");   
    }

    void spWeigh_DataInReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        strResponseWeigh = spWeigh.ReadLine();         
        string wt = strResponseWeigh.Substring(5, 7);
        this.TxtFrstWt.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(sin_DataReceived), new object[] { wt });
    }

    private void sin_DataReceived(string data)
    {
        TxtFrstWt.Text = data.Trim();
        TxtDateIn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");         
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!spWeigh.IsOpen)
            spWeigh.Open();
        spWeigh.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(spWeigh_DataOutReceived);
        spWeigh.Write("W");   
    }

    void spWeigh_DataOutReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        strResponseWeigh = spWeigh.ReadLine();               
        string wt = strResponseWeigh.Substring(5, 7);               
        this.TxtFrstWt.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(sout_DataReceived), new object[] { wt });
    }
    private void sout_DataReceived(string data)
    {
        TxtScndryWt.Text = data.Trim();
        TxtDateOut.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this two seperate devices attached to the COM port?  And why not open the port once and just read from it twice?

Comment: Did you just wire these two scales to the same COM port?  That can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I got this right.

You're saying that you have a device connected to the serial port and that you need to read the information twice from there, right?

Your code is a bit convulted when dealing with that. I'd redo it in a bit more like this:

```
SerialPort spWeigh;
string strResponseWeigh;

private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    spWeigh = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    spWeigh.RtsEnable = false;
    spWeigh.DtrEnable = false;
    spWeigh.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    spWeigh.ReadTimeout = 10000; 
    spWeigh.DataReceived += spWeigh_DataInReceived;
    spWeigh.Open();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    spWeigh.Write("W"); 
}

void spWeigh_DataInReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    strResponseWeigh = spWeigh.ReadLine();
    string wt = strResponseWeigh.Substring(5, 7);
    this.TxtFrstWt.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(sin_DataReceived), new object[] { wt });
}

private void sin_DataReceived(string data)
{
    TxtFrstWt.Text = data.Trim();
    TxtDateIn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

You see, you don't need to attach event handlers every time you click the button, that's why the line

```
spWeigh.DataReceived += spWeigh_DataInReceived;
```

appears to the `MainWindow_Loaded` event handler.

Trying to open a serial connection more than once might cause some problems, that too went to the loaded event handler.

If I understand the process correctly, every time the device received a `W` through the serial interface, it spills out the weight in the scale through the same serial port, right?

This way all you need to do is to send a 'W' when you click the button and the results should appear on the data received event handler.

Comment: You're right, we have to attach the event handler only once. Its working fine without any errors now... thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's going to work. Why do you even need two connections to the serial port anyway?

Read the weight from the port in whatever way this is done and save the result.
Then repeat the step with the loaded one.
Calculate the difference and you're done.

Why would you like to use two instances of `SerialPort`? It's not like you'd have to save the result inside these objects.

Comment: Hi Mario, I had an error when updating the results from the serial port to a textbox (different thread owns it) , but i sorted that using the dispatcher.begininvoke method.  but now the problem is that when i take the second weight, its not showing the weight and when i click the second time, it shows the weight and on further clicking it updates the first weight.